# Selenium IDE for Firefox not reading values from PHP report form

Tags: find, selenium-ide, verification

I have report forms in PhP and I need to read the elements on it, but the tool is not reading the values to validate it.
When I hit 'Find' button the tool is able to read the value, but when I run the whole test case, its not.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the page isn't fully loaded before you try to read the value?
Can you waitForElementPresent for that element?